# Keycloak Token api PKCE code verifier not specified

Tags: oauth-2.0, nuxt.js, keycloak

I attempted to authenticate the vuejs application with Kecloak, but I received a PKCE code verifier not specified error while attempting to exchange an authorization code for an access token using the keycloak token api (http://localhost:8080/realms/kredo-dev/protocol/openid-connect/token).

I am sending code, client_id, redirect_uri, response_type, grant_type in the payload.

The error for the request is {"error": "invalid_grant," "error_description": "PKCE code verifier not specified"}

Comment: The error is quite self-explanatory here, you probably need a code of some sort. Did you checked this page: https://www.keycloak.org/securing-apps/vue Otherwise, which documentation page do you refer to right now?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Going to take a wild guess that you're using keycloak-js. When you initialize your keycloak object, ensure you specify pkceMethod.

```
keycloak.init({
    ...
    pkceMethod: "S256"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this ussue but with spring, i solved by implementing the code_verifier like this:

1. generate code_verifier from a ramdom string through this link: https://example-app.com/pkce
2. generate code_challenge from code_verifier using the same link as above
3. authorize user using the code_challenge generated in item 2
4. request token using the code_verifier generated in item 1

i followed these tutorials:

- https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/authentication.htm#ESRI_SECTION3_72BB056056CB4F35A1A17EF1D3BEBEA6
- https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/add-login-using-the-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce#create-code-verifier